# Async/await did not make an asynchronous effect

Tags: vb.net, async-await

Async/await has no effect，

I think label1 should be executed immediately.

```
 Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                       End Sub)
        Label1.Text = "123"
    End Sub
```

Comment: what's the observed behaviour and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: The assumption is wrong. `async/await` means that the UI thread won't be blocked while waiting for the task to complete. If you tried to use `Thread.Sleep(3000)` directly, the application would hang for 3 seconds.

Comment: `Label1` would be updated immediatelly only if `await` *didn't* work. `await` waits for an already executing asynchronous operation to complete without blocking the original thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how `Async/Await` is supposed to work. in your code:

```
 Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                   End Sub)
    Label1.Text = "123"
 End Sub
```

`label1`will not change before the 3sec delay is over. your event handler awaits the task, and then continues execution, changing the label. But `Async/Await`definitly has an effect.

compare your code to this one:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Label1.Text = "123"
 End Sub
```

the same thing will happen as in your code: after 3secs the label will change. However, there is one huge difference; in your code, the `Async/await`version, the UI **doesn't block** which means you could press another button and the code there would still execute immediatly.

`Await` signals that there's a long task going on, and the UI thread will not continue executing the `sub` until that task completes (on a different thread). once it does, the UI thread will pick up where it left of and update the label.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the following and the code is more like asynchronous

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim action1 As Action = New Action(Sub()
                                               Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                                           End Sub)
        action1.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
        Label1.Text = "123"


    End Sub
```